# vue-konva: removing specific node from stage working incorrectly

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

I'm passing down an array of image urls as props to my Konva component, creating a image object for each url, storing that object in a data object (using Vue's `$set` method to keep the object literal reactive), then using `v-for` to create a `v-image` for each image object in my data object. This seems to be working fine, however I'm running into a problem where if I try to remove one of the images, 2 images will be removed. This only happens if the image that I try to remove is not the topmost image. In the console, I'm getting the warning `Konva warning: Node has no parent. zIndex parameter is ignored.`. My hunch is that this is a result of konva's `destroy` method clashing with vue's `$delete` method on a data object used in a `v-for`. I've been battling with this for hours, and would appreciate any help I can get. Relevant code is below. Thanks!

Parent

```
<template>
  <editor ref="editor" :image-props.sync="images"/>
  <button @click="remove">remove</button>
</template>
export default {
  components: {
    Editor,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      images: [url1, url2, etc...],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    remove() {
      this.$refs.editor.removeSelectedImage();
    },
}
```

child

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-stage>
      <v-layer>
        <v-group>
          <v-image v-for="image in Object.values(images)" 
           :key="image.id" :config="image"/>
        </v-group>
      </v-layer>
    </v-stage>
  </div>
</template>
export default {
  props: {
    imageProps: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      images: {},
      selectedNode: null //this gets updated on click
    },
  watch: {
    imageProps() {
      this.registerImages();
    },
  mounted() {
    this.registerImages();
  },
  methods: {
    registerImages() {
      this.imageProps.forEach(url => {
         if (!this.images[url]) {
           let img = new Image();
           img.src = url;
           img.onload = () => {
              this.$set(this.images, url, {
                 image: img,
                 draggable: true,
                 name: url,
                 x: 0,
                 y: 0,
              });
           }
        }
     });
  },
  removeSelectedLayer() {
     let newImageProps = this.imageProps.filter(url => url !== this.selectedImageName);
     this.$emit('update:image-props', newImageProps);
     this.selectedNode.destroy();
     this.$delete(this.images, this.selectedImageName);
     this.stageArea.draw();
},
```

If I inspect the component in Vue devtools, the `images` object looks correct as well as `imageProps`, (even the Vue DOM tree looks right with the correct amount of `v-image`s) however the canvas shows 1 less image than it should. Again, this only happens if I remove a image that wasn't initially on top. It seems to function fine if I remove the top-most image.

Comment: Can you make an online demo? But basically, you should not remove nodes manually from the canvas. Instead, just remove an item from an array in `data`.

Comment: sorry for the delay in response. Here is a quick demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/nkv4908mx4. Notice that it will remove multiple layers if you don't have the topmost layer selected

Comment: Also please note that if you comment out the `destroy()` call, it will remove the correct node but the second from the top node will then snap to the position of the removed node.

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing an app with `vue-konva` it is better not to touch `Konva` nodes manually (there only rare cases when you need it, like updating `Konva.Transformer`).

You don't need to call `node.destroy()` manually. Just an item for your `data`.

From your demo, I see you are not using `key` attribute (you are using `image.id` for that, but it is `undefined`). It is very important to use keys in such case.

Updated demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/30qpxpx38q

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! And thanks for such a great library! I'm having a lot of fun with Konva.